# Cannot connect to aws redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I created a redshift in aws console. the I went to cluster created and based on the information I got in the console I used them in SQL Workbench/J. 
To set up sql workbench/J I used the following:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html

So here is my setup:

[image]

Now when I try to connect to it I get the following:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix it or what is going on?

***UPDATE***

I also gave inbound security group of the VPC which I had my redshift in full access to the IP address I am conncting and the same issue

Also here is the full logs:

```
  2018-01-18 16:39:36 ERROR Error connecting to the database using 
  URL=jdbc:redshift://hamedtest.cb1dy4xxxxxxxxxxx [Amazon](500150) Error 
   setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect. [SQL 
   State=HY000, DB Errorcode=500150] 
     java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing 
   connection: Connection timed out: connect.
   at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.core.PGJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at workbench.db.DbDriver.connect(DbDriver.java:513)
at workbench.db.ConnectionMgr.connect(ConnectionMgr.java:255)
at workbench.db.ConnectionMgr.getConnection(ConnectionMgr.java:182)
at workbench.gui.components.ConnectionSelector.doConnect(ConnectionSelector.java:22
7)
 Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Amazon](500150) 
  Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out: connect.
```

Comment: Do you have any unusual characters in your password?

Comment: @JohnHanley no it is sth like this: Ss111122

Comment: If possible, try it from a different network (eg home vs work) to rule out a networking blockage.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for your suggestion this never came to my mind migh be because proxy??

Comment: The full error should be logged in the application's logfile (Help -> View logfile).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes you are right I added the full log

Comment: "*Connection timed out: connect*" indicates a problem with your network. Some firewall or simply an incorrect hostname

Comment: Yes it was a network issue please add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 4):

Did you choose "Publicly accessible" `YES` (radio button) when creating your cluster? If that is set to `NO` then you can **only** access the cluster from inside your VPC.

You easily change this in the console by navigating to the cluster, clicking the `Cluster ˅` button, clicking `Modify`. Then change the "Publicly accessible" selection and click the blue `Modify` button.

Comment: Good to know thanks I never noticed that but when I checked now it is publicly accessible

Comment: In reality I wouldnt make it publicly accessible though. Instead, focus on accessing it either through a secure VPN or tunnel, or a mixture of both. After that has been set you can use port forwarding to do the connect.